# Saving Exported PDF File to Specified Location in ASP.NET Project Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

May i know how to specify the path to save the exported PDF File with the codes below?

The file will be later required to be used as an attachment with an email.

Been looking at different posts on stackoverflow can't seem to find one that solves my issue.

```
protected void BTN_Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40f, 40f, 40f, 40f);
        Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Font BoldFontForHeader = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 13, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);

        //String path = Server.MapPath("C:\\Users\\Dom\\Downloads\\WebFormApplication\\WebFormApplication\\WebFormApplication\\Exported Documents");

        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, memoryStream);

            //var output = new FileStream(Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\Dom\\Downloads\\WebFormApplication\\WebFormApplication\\WebFormApplication\\Exported Documents", "BedsListExport.pdf"), FileMode.Create);

            //PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
            //Phrase phrase = null;
            PdfPCell cell = null;
            //PdfPTable bedsTable = null;

            PdfPTable bedsTable = new PdfPTable(Beds.HeaderRow.Cells.Count);
            bedsTable.TotalWidth = 550f;
            bedsTable.LockedWidth = true;
            bedsTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            bedsTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.5f });
            bedsTable.SpacingBefore = 30f;

            //Headers
            string[] headersName = { "Bed ID", "Patient ID", "Patient Name", "Class", "Block", "Level", "Staff Incharge ID", "Date & Time Assigned" };

            for (int i = 0; i < headersName.Length; i++)
            {
                PdfPCell hCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headersName[i].ToString(), BoldFontForHeader));
                bedsTable.AddCell(hCell);
            }

            foreach (GridViewRow row in Beds.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell tableCell in row.Cells)
                {
                    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tableCell.Text));
                    cell.Padding = 5;
                    bedsTable.AddCell(cell);
                }
            }

            pdfDocument.Open();

            //Top of Document

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Mount Olympus Hospital", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18));
            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("24 Jalan Kapal Street 42 Singapore 554524", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12));
            Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("Telephone: 6550-9514 Fax: 6550-9245", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12));

            p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            p2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            p3.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            pdfDocument.Add(p1);
            pdfDocument.Add(p2);
            pdfDocument.Add(p3);

            Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph("Beds List", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 16));
            p4.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            p4.SpacingBefore = 20f;

            pdfDocument.Add(p4);

            pdfDocument.Add(bedsTable);

            pdfDocument.Close();

            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=BedsListExport.pdf");
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.End();
            Response.Close();

        }

    }
```

Added these lines of codes, but still doesn't work

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath("C:\\Users\\Dom\\Downloads\\WebFormApplication\\WebFormApplication\\WebFormApplication\\Exported Documents") + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                memoryStream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
```

I have tried different lines of codes from different sources too. This is my first time using MemoryStream, FileStream and iTextSharp...

Appreciate any help please.